# extract text from a file until a matching line in perl

Tags: regex, perl, while-loop, cygwin, do-while

I have a large file. I am trying that is parse it to extract the value that is associated with the word Etot.There are multiple entries of Etot. i want to extract all the values until the search hits the line "AVERAGES OVER". I am using cygwin. Here is what I have so far

```
$filename= "data.txt";
open($FILE. "$filename") ||die "cannot open the file $filename: $!";
do {

while ($str = <$FILE>)
chomp $str;

if ( $str =~ /Etot/) {
print substr($str, 1,-55). "\n";
}

until ($str =~ "AVERAGES OVER")

}
close($FILE);

close($fh);
```

Comment: Your sample code has multiple syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

You are making it more complicated than it needs to be. You only need a single loop to achieve what you need

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename= "data.txt";
open(my $FILE, "$filename") 
    || die "cannot open the file $filename: $!\n";

while (my $str = <$FILE>)
{
    print substr($str, 1,-55). "\n"
        if $str =~ /Etot/;

    last 
        if $str =~ /AVERAGES OVER/;
}
close($FILE);
```

Comment: Thank you @pmqs . I will try this now and get back to you

Comment: No, that isn't necessary. I tested the script before I posted it to check it worked, so there shouldn't be any syntax errors. What is the syntax error you are getting?

Comment: @MO12, More importantly, what did you change?

Comment: @MO12, `if` statement: `if (COND_EXPR) BLOCK` // `if` statement modifier: `EXPR if COND_EXPR;`

Comment: @MO12 I've copied the code I posted & ran it again, just in case I did a cut-and-paste error. Still works fine for me.  Can you check again that you haven't accidentally changed it while you copied it?

Comment: `open(my $FILE, "$filename")` should be `open(my $FILE, "<", $filename)`. (Needless use of stringification. Needless use of problematic two-arg `open`.)

Comment: @ikegami -that's a valid change to make, but not enough to trigger the syntax error

Comment: Correct. It just makes the code nicer (more or less). It doesn't fix any syntax errors because there are no syntax errors to fix.

Comment: Running on cygwin shouldn't make any difference @MO12. Perl syntax is the same on all platforms. Also the format of the data you are reading is not relevant -- the syntax error means the code will not get a chance to run and read "data.txt".

Comment: Make sure the line that is testing for the AVERAGES OVER is this -->  if $str =~ /AVERAGES OVER/ ;

Comment: @pmqs when you get a chance can you explain this. /AVERAGES OVER/  (what are the forward slashes doing.

Comment: The forward slashes are used to delimit a "regular expression" (see https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html). In this instance there are no special regular expression meta characters being used, so the expression $str =~ /AVERAGES OVER/ can be read as "Does $str contain the literal string 'AVERAGES OVER' anywhere.